# Does knockout-validation interfere with custom extenders?

Tags: validation, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm using KnockoutJS 2.2.1 along with Knockout-Validation.
Is there maybe a known bug with interference between validation and creating custom extenders?

Because somehow I cannot add my custom extender.
When I try to run this code:

```
self.from = ko.observable(new Date()).extend({ reportDate: { timeZoneValue: self.timeZoneValue} });
```

where reportDate is my extender, knockout-validation seems to have problem, that he can't find "rules for undefined"

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rules' of undefined

Did somebody had this problem? How to solve it?

Here is the code for reportDate extender:

```
ko.extenders.reportDate = function (target, options) {
var lastValidValue = new Date();

target.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    if (newValue == null) {
        target(lastValidValue);
    } else {
        lastValidValue = newValue;
    }
    var isoDate = moment(DateProvider.adjustDateFromTimeZoneToUtc(target(), options.timeZoneValue())).toISOString();
    target.ISODateString = isoDate;
});
```

};

I also wonder if knockout-validation's custom rules can break something here. Especially registerExtenders() function which is not clear for me what it does.

```
$(function () {
ko.validation.init({
    insertMessages: true,
    decorateElement: true,
    errorElementClass: "error",
    errorMessageClass: "validation-message",
    grouping: { observable: true, deep: true }
});

ko.validation.registerExtenders();
```

});

Comment: Generally extenders should work side by side, but it depends on your custom extender implementation, so can you please post your `reportDate` code? Also in your sample I don't see where/how do you use  the ko.validaiton, so can you also extend your example to show how you are using the validation plugin? A jsfiddle repro would be the most ideal to help with your problem...

Comment: I have added more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your extender does not return any observable. From [the documentation on extending observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html):

> It can then either return the observable or return something new 
>   like a computed observable that uses the original observable in some way.

So you should problaby add the following line as the last code line in your extender (unless you want to return a different observable object, in which case you should of course do that instead):

```
return target;
```

Comment: Thank You very much for that! I was even wondering if it's necessary to return my target observable, but it wasn't said clear enough for me that you MUST return it. And the knockout validation misslead me even more.

Comment: @TomaszSikora The reason you need to return the observable from the method call is that the next extender added will receive the return value from your extender as `target`. Thus, if you don't return any object, the target will be undefined and thus cause the error you were seeing. Also, I believe the extend method will in the end return the returned value from the last extender.